# How to make input pipeline using tf.RandomShuffleQueue and tf.train.shuffle_batch in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

While studying deeplearning, there was a problem that the model did not work due to the problem of computer (cpu, ram and etc).

the model: 8 layers model
data: numpy array (20000, 20, 20, 3)

So I tried to apply the queue to the model but it failed.

This is what I want to do.
https://www.tensorflow.org/images/AnimatedFileQueues.gif

The difference is that I do not use filename.
I use numpy array.

Please let me know what the problem is and how to fix it.

If you have any additional references, please provide url.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N_SAMPLES = 1000; NUM_THREADS = 3
all_data = 10 * np.random.randn(N_SAMPLES, 4) + 1
all_target = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=N_SAMPLES)

queue = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity = 200, 
                              min_after_dequeue = 51,
                              dtypes=[tf.float32, tf.int32], 
                              shapes=[[4], []], 
                              names=None, 
                              seed=20, 
                              shared_name=None, 
                              name='random_shuffle_queue')
enqueue_op = queue.enqueue_many([all_data, all_target])
data_sample, label_sample = queue.dequeue()
qr = tf.train.QueueRunner(queue, [enqueue_op] * NUM_THREADS)

train_data_batch, train_labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data_sample, label_sample],
                                                              capacity=200, 
                                                              min_after_dequeue=51, 
                                                              enqueue_many=False, 
                                                              batch_size=50, 
                                                              seed=20)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # create a coordinator, launch the queue runner threads.
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    enqueue_threads = qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, start=True)
    for step in range(10): # do to 10 iterations
        if coord.should_stop():
            break
        one_data, one_label = sess.run([train_data_batch, train_labels_batch])
        print(one_label) # I don't know why it doesn't executed
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(enqueue_threads)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use [`tf.train.slice_input_producer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/train/slice_input_producer)

```
data_sample, label_sample = slice_input_producer(
    [all_data, all_target], num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True, seed=None, capacity=1000, shared_name=None, name=None)
train_data_batch, train_labels_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([data_sample, label_sample],
    capacity=200, min_after_dequeue=51, enqueue_many=False, batch_size=50, seed=20)
```